# while importing Ag-GridModule getting error

Tags: angular, ag-grid

**'ag-grid-angular' is not a known element:**

```
 <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 500px; margin-top: 10px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"

16                 [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [rowHeight]="30"
   
17  `               [headerHeight]="30">
```

I have install `npm i --save ag-grid-community ag-grid-angular`

and import in app module

```
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular/main';
```

I have imported all required things still why i'm getting the above error,
i  am using Angular v16.
is these version issue or i did wrong?

Comment: you should provide AgGridModule in the module where you component that is rendering <ag-grid..> is declared. or, if the component is a standalone component - in the component's `imports`

Answer (score 0):

You should import it in app module like below:

```
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
```

and add it in imports array:

```
imports: [
  // ...
  AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
  // ...
],
```